# attempted relative import with no known parent package when running CrawlerProcess

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Here is the structure of my python crawler project

```
tmallspider (a folder)
spiders (a folder)
    tmall_spider.py
items.py
```

I am working in tmall_spider.py and I want to import from items.py

```
from ..items import TmallspiderItem
```

This statement works and my program runs if I type the following in terminal:

```
scrapy crawl tspider
```

However, there is an error:

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

If I add a crawlerProcess and try to run tmall_spider.py. My CrawlerProcess is like this:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings=None, install_root_handler=True)
process.crawl('tspider')
process.start()
```

Any idea how to fix it? I need the CrawlerProcess because I want to run multiple spiders sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an absolute import instead of a relative? Double check the spelling of your files and the class within items.py , looking at the piece of code it should work.

I wouldn't worry about CrawlerProcess, shouldn't interfere with a relative import.

Comment: I tried from __future__ import absolute_import, but the same error occurs. I don't think spelling is the issue because if I run the two spiders individually in terminal, this import error won't occur

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by from future import absolute_import.
https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#absolute-imports
Gives a break down of what an absolute import is.
In your case the absolute import would be from tmallspider.items import TmallspiderItem.
Tmallspider is the project folder and you're importing items.py, from that TmallspiderItem class.